# Bug in the validator or obscure error in my CSS?

Tags: css, w3c, validation

I am trying to validate a CSS document with the W3C validator, and it's giving some warnings related to color and background-color that should not appear since, well, I don't have those issues present in my document. Having it incorrectly report a warning wouldn't be so much of a surprise, but it reports *different warnings every time the SAME document is validated!*

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.petroules.com%2Fcss%2Fphotocrayze%2F0-site.css&profile=css21&usermedium=all&warning=2&vextwarning=false&lang=en

Try clicking that link to validate the document, and refresh a few times - notice it'll report a different set of errors each time.

I can't figure this out for the life of me - is this a known issue? I've only been able to reproduce it with this particular document.

Comment: I don't see any errors, just warnings. Still, very strange.

Comment: Wicked.  Do yourself a favor:  If the tool says it is red, when, in fact it is blue:  Trust your instincts.  It looks to me that their validator is on the fritz.

Comment: Maybe `body {background: url('/images/photocrayze/bg3.png') repeat-x #fff;}` ? maybe not.

Comment: There are no rules for the order of attributes within a rule, right?

Comment: I tested your style sheet with a different location and W3C validator, validates without any warnings. Their bad not yours.

Comment: @Jake: Very few rules, maybe none.  Since duplicate properties are generally not expected within a rule, i'm not sure whether there's a rule about that.  Generally, if there are, the last one wins...but i'm not sure if that's invalid CSS to even have them.  Other than that, stuff can appear in any order you like.

Comment: @Stack 101 What do you mean a different location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [copy the CSS](http://static.petroules.com/css/photocrayze/0-site.css) and [paste it into here](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input) it validates without any warnings.
I'd just put it down to validator weirdness.

Comment: BTW I should note I'm using 'all warnings' (although my URL did have that parameter set). It give me a random number of warnings no matter what way I input it. But yeah, just validator weirdness I guess. Do they have a bugtracker available?